# powershell accessing a value by property name instead of index

Tags: powershell

ITs been my 2nd day on powershell scripts.

I have a powershell script as below;

```
Search-AdminAuditLog -Cmdlets add-rolegroupmember,remove-rolegroupmember -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate -Parameters member |
where { $_.objectmodified -like '*'+$RoleGroupName} |
select 'objectmodified','Caller','Rundate','cmdletname',@{Name='Username';Expression={$***_.cmdletparameters.Value[1]***}}
```

How do I access the  value of the expression `_.cmdletparameters.Value[1]`   something like `_.cmdletparameters.Value['Name']` instead of the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the scriptblock in your impromptu hashtable through a Where statement like most anything else. Try something like this:

```
@{l='Username';e={$_.cmdletparameters|?{$_.Name -like "UserID"}|select -expandproperty Value}}
```

Comment: Thanks . I solved it like below;      $startDate='01/03/2013'
$endDate='19/03/2014'

Search-AdminAuditLog -Cmdlets add-rolegroupmember,remove-rolegroupmember -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate -Parameters member | where {$_.succeeded -eq $True} | select 'objectmodified','Caller','Rundate','cmdletname',@{Name='Username';Expression={($_.cmdletparameters|where {$_.Name -eq 'Member'}).Value  }}

Comment: sername';Expression={(‌​$_.cmdletparameters|where {$_.Name -eq 'Member'}).Value }}